# Adding sorting to a view on Drupal?

Tags: drupal, sorting, drupal-views

I used to know how to do this, but I can't seem to get sorting to work on a view where filters are exposed in a block. I want to be able to filter by, for example, type, price etc, but then also have sorting options to sort by these items.

How do I get sorting to work like this?

Comment: Out of curiosity did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I'm trying 451F's approach. And no. But I'm going to try impliment the views_query_alter hook and see what happens. Will report back when I get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used that code to override sorting in non-table views

```
function views_tweak_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'products'){
  if (arg(3) == 'pu') $query->orderby[0]='uc_products_sell_price ASC';
  if (arg(3) == 'pd') $query->orderby[0]='uc_products_sell_price DESC';
  if (arg(3) == 'nu') $query->orderby[0]='node_title ASC';
  if (arg(3) == 'nd') $query->orderby[0]='node_title DESC';

  } 
}
```

and placing into view template links with those urls

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you implemented this? Did you put this in template.php? Or where exactly? And when is this hook called? Every time a view is, erm, viewed?

Comment: I put this in separate module. Hook alteres a view query to change sorting. Called every time. In view I add 4 links (sort name up, sort name down, sort price up and sort price down). In $query->orderby[0] stored field and direction for sorting.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't expose sort criteria like you can with filters.

I looked a bit around a found [this module](http://drupal.org/project/viewsdisplaytabs). The idea is to create several views each with a different sort criteria and link them together with tabs. It's a bit hackish and might not work with exposed filters. The module is still in beta release, and I haven't tested it, so can't say if it's any good.

Comment: I remember specifically having set an option in the past, that would show dropdowns at the top of the view. I want to know how to do that again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you cannot find where to set this, look on the left side of the View (in Edit mode), under Basic Settings, select "Table". The click the "settings" (looks like a little gear icon to the right of the "table" selection), and you'll see a list of all the display fields, where you can select which ones are sortable/not, and which is the default sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use a table layout, you can sort by columns. That functionality is built into views.

Answer (score 0):

Adding sorting to a view on Drupal less programm code in hooks.

You need to use arguments in display page.

Use taxonomy menu for pages before.. Next:

1. Create one display page in view with path (for example):
   some_path/%/by_totalcount
   1.1. Make sort criteria for this display by totalcount
2. Make another one dislplay page in this view with path (for example):
   some_path/%/by_date
   2.1. Make sort criteria for this display by date
3. Create new block with code:

<?php 


$url= urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

switch($url)
{
   case '1': 
      $class = 'top'; 
      $title_h2 = 'top';
   break;
   case '/taxonomy/term/6 3 ': 
     $class = 'travel';
     $title_h2 = 'travel'; 
   break;
.................
}

global $base_url;

$url_rating = $base_url.'/'.arg(0).'/'.arg(1).'/'.arg(2).'/rating'; 
$url_created = $base_url.'/'.arg(0).'/'.arg(1).'/'.arg(2);

?>
<div class="<?php print  $class; ?>">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>
            <?php print  $title_h2; ?></h2>
        <p>Sort node: <span class="sort_type"><a href="<?php echo $url_rating; ?>">by rate</a></span> | <span class="sort_type"> <a href="<?php echo $url_created; ?>">by date</a></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

VOILA

---

Sorry for my english.. it isn't my native language ))

---

Comment: Consider using l() function to generate a tags. You don't even want to get $base_url - l() can do most of the heavy lifting for you.